# C++ empty array size

Tags: c++, c++11

I initialized an array in three different ways (either on heap or on stack), but contrary to my expectation, there appears to be two different values for their size. I don't understand why.

```
int asd[0];    
sizeof(asd);   //ouput 0;   

int asd={};
sizeof(asd);    //output 4;

int *asd=new int[0];
sizeof(asd);    //output 4;
```

Since an array name is a pointer to an allocated memory block and as the size of a pointer is 4, I consider that outputs 2 and 3 are correct.

But what I don't understand is why the output 1 is not showing size 4.

Comment: C++ does not allow arrays of size zero. ([Demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/A5xdIaY4Ezdrpdre))

Comment: but it works in my compiler

Comment: is second form correct according to the standard?

Comment: So what? What has your compiler to do with correct C++?

Comment: The second form is not an array, it's just a single `int`.

Comment: And the third returns the size of the pointer, not the array.

Comment: since array with size zero doesn't exist when then second one; i think it is also empty array. shouldn't it be invalid? how second one is an int?I understand how 3 one works.please enlighten me on 1 and 2 one?

Comment: Add `-Wpedantic` to your command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last two of your examples are not arrays;

The first is: `int asd[0]` is defining an array of size 0, which is not allowed.

> If the expression is a constant expression, it shall have a value greater than zero.

The second: `int asd={};` is `int` using aggregate initializaion. The size of `int` 4 bytes.

The third: `int *asd=new int[0];` is a pointer of type `int` pointing to a dynamically allocated memory. The size of the pointer is `4 bytes` (2^32 addresses).

Comment: but i dont understand why this is not allowed on stack while allowed on heap?

Comment: it has to do with the C standard, see here : https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html